# I keep getting the errors no match for 'operator[]', 'A', 'J' and 'N' were not declared in my code. what is the problem with it?

Tags: c++, matrix

This is the code for my matrix class
The goal here was to Complete the member functions 'void Matrix::add(const Matrix &), void Matrix::mul(double),
void Matrix::mul(const Matrix &), void Matrix::tr(void), and void Matrix::eye(int)'
of the Matrix class in the header file file matrix class
but as soon as I completed that my code started giving me errors and will not run. I am not sure what the problem is.

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H_
#define MATRIX_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define ROW_MAX 10
#define COL_MAX 10

// In the following, the matrix object is referred to as A,
// upper case letters denote matrices,
// and lover case letters denote scalars.
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int m_, int n_, double v_) : m(m_), n(n_) { fill(v_); }; // constructor for an m_ x n_ matrix A initialized to v_
    Matrix(int m_, int n_) : Matrix(m_, n_, 0.0) {}                 // constructor for an m_ x n_ matrix A initialized to 0.0
    Matrix(int m_) : Matrix(m_, m_) {}                              // constructor for an m_ x m_ matrix A initialized to 0.0
    Matrix() : Matrix(0) {}                                         // constructor for a 0 x 0 matrix A (empty matrix)
    Matrix(const Matrix &A_) { set(A_); }                           // copy constructor
    void from_str(const string &str_);                              // reads in m, n, and the matrix elements from the string str_ in the format of "m n A[0][0] A[0][1]...A[m-1][n-1]"
    string to_str(void);                                            // returns the string representation of A in the format of "m n A[0][0] A[0][1]...A[m-1][n-1]"
    int getRows(void) const;                                        // returns the number of rows
    int getCols(void) const;                                        // returns the number of columns
    double get(int i_, int j_) const;                               // returns A[i_][j_]
    void set(int i_, int j_, double v_);                            // sets A[i_][j_] to v_ (A[i_][j_] = v_)
    void set(const Matrix &A_);                                     // sets A to A_ (A = A_)
    void add(const Matrix &A_);                                     // adds A_ to A (A := A + A_)
    void mul(double v_);                                            // multiplies A by the scalar v_ (A := v_ A)
    void mul(const Matrix &A_);                                     // multiplies A by A_ (A := A A_)
    void tr(void);                                                  // sets A to its transpose (A := A^T)
    void eye(int m_);                                               // sets A to the m_ x m_ identity matrix (A := I)
private:
    int m;                         // the number of rows
    int n;                         // the number of cols
    void setRows(int m_);          // sets the number of rows to m_
    void setCols(int n_);          // sets the number of columns to n_
    double data[ROW_MAX][COL_MAX]; // holds the matrix data as 2D array
    void fill(double v_);          // fills the matrix with v_
};

void Matrix::fill(double v_)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < getRows(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCols(); j++)
        {
            set(i, j, v_);
        }
    }
}

void Matrix::from_str(const string &str_)
{
    istringstream stream(str_);
    int m_ = 0, n_ = 0;
    stream >> m_;
    stream >> n_;
    setRows(m_);
    setCols(n_);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double v_;
    while (stream >> v_)
    {
        set(i, j, v_);
        j += 1;
        if (j == getCols())
        {
            i = i + 1;
            j = 0;
        }

        if (i == getRows())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

string Matrix::to_str(void)
{
    ostringstream _stream("");
    _stream << getRows() << " " << getCols();
    for (int i = 0; i < getRows(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCols(); j++)
        {
            _stream << " " << fixed << defaultfloat << get(i, j);
        }
    }

    return _stream.str();
}

int Matrix::getRows(void) const
{
    return m;
}

int Matrix::getCols(void) const
{
    return n;
}

void Matrix::setRows(int m_)
{
    m = m_;
}

void Matrix::setCols(int n_)
{
    n = n_;
}

double Matrix::get(int i_, int j_) const
{
    return data[i_][j_];
}

void Matrix::set(int i_, int j_, double v_)
{
    data[i_][j_] = v_;
}

void Matrix::set(const Matrix &A_)
{
    setRows(A_.getRows());
    setCols(A_.getCols());
    for (int i = 0; i < getRows(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCols(); j++)
        {
            set(i, j, A_.get(i, j));
        }
    }
}

void Matrix::add(const Matrix &A_)
{
    int r = getRows();
    int c = getCols();
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
             A_[i][j] = A_[i][j] + A_[i][j];
        }
    }


}

void Matrix::mul(double v_)
{
     int r = getRows();
     int c = getCols();
     for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
         {
             A[i][j] = v_ * A[i][j];
         }

     }


}

void Matrix::mul(const Matrix &A_)
{
    int r = getRows();
    int c = getCols();
    int result[r][c];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < r; k++)
            {
                result[i][j] += A[i][k] * A_[k][j];
            }

        }

    }

}

void Matrix::tr(void)
{
    int r = getRows();
    int c = getCols();
    int result[r][c];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (intj = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
             result[i][j] = A[j][i];
        }

    }

}

void Matrix::eye(int m_)
{
     int r = getRows();
     int c = getCols();
     for (int row = 0; row < m_; row++)
     {
         for (int col = 0; col < m_; col++)
         {
              if (row == col)
                A[row][col] = 1;
              else
                A[row][col] = 0;
         }

     }

}

#endif
```

Comment: You don't have `operator[]` for something we don't know since we don't know the error. Also somewhere you are using A, J, and N without defining them... For example in `Matrix::tr` you have `intj = 0` instead of `int j = 0`

Comment: The code uses `A_[i][j]` when it should be using `A_.data[i][j]`.

Comment: I'd also look askance at a non-template class fully defined in a header, enclosed by header guards...

Comment: `lover case` probably ought to be `lowercase`.  But I admit I like the notion of *lover case*, because it sounds romantic.

Comment: That is a LOT of code for a compilation error. You should pick *one* error (specifically, the first error), and remove what is not needed to reproduce that error. Compilation errors usually do not require more than a dozen lines to reproduce, often less. The goal of your [mre] is not to demonstrate anything about matrices, but to demonstrate your specific error message. In fact, a good example might no longer be recognizable as a "matrix class".

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a few problems in your code. For example, in 'add', you have the following:

```
A_[i][j] = A_[i][j] + A_[i][j];
```

However, `A_` is `const`, so you can't be modifying its data. Further, the `Matrix` class does not have an `operator[]`, so you can't use `A_[i]` in the first place. You likely want the following:

```
data[i][j] = A_.data[i][j] + A_.data[i][j];
```

In your `mul(double v_)` function, you have the following line:

```
A[i][j] = v_ * A[i][j];
```

Again, there is no `operator[]` for your matrix, so it's not valid. Further, this function does not even have an `A` defined. You want to deal with the `data` directly.

```
data[i][j] = v_ * data[i][j];
```

In the `mul(const Matrix &A_)` you again have similar issues with using `[]`, and again you have an `A` instead of `A_`. There's other issues in this function, such as not using the `result` after you've done the calculations.

In the `tr` function, you have `intj` instead of `int j`, and you're using a variable `N` which is not defined.

The function `eye` references the variable `A` which, again, never defined. You want `data`.

Using an IDE, or even an online compiler like godbolt, points out exactly where every one of these errors are. You can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/arn6cvGro) a fixed version of the code, though this doesn't fix any logic errors, just the syntax ones.